# Predict visible index paths when scroll view didEndDragging

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with horizontal flow layout and fixed-width cells.  When user ends dragging, I want to get a head start on fetching content for items that *will be* visible when deceleration finishes.

For that, I need the index paths that will be visible at the end of deceleration.  I think this code works, but is lame (for obvious reasons, I think, just a few of them described in comments):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    // already bummed here: 
    // a) this seems the wrong way to get the fixed cell width
    // b) sad that this method precludes variable width cells
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *la = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:self.collectionView.bounds][0];
    CGFloat width = la.size.width;

    // this must be wrong, too.  what about insets, header views, etc?
    NSInteger firstVisible = floorf(targetContentOffset->x / width);

    NSInteger visibleCount = ceilf(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width / width);
    NSInteger lastVisible = MIN(firstVisible+visibleCount, self.model.count);
    NSMutableArray *willBeVisibleIndexPaths = [@[] mutableCopy];

    // neglecting sections
    for (NSInteger i=firstVisible; i<lastVisible; i++) {
        [willBeVisibleIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    }
}
```

This is a lot of brittle code to do something that seems straight-forward.  If I wanted it to handle sections, insets, aux views,  variable cells, etc. it would quickly become a buggy, inefficient tangle.

Please tell me I'm missing something simple already in the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to make use of the `UICollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:` method.

Calculate the top-left and bottom-right points of the visible area of the collection view based on the `targetContentOffset` and the collection view's `contentSize`.

Then use those two points to get the two corresponding `indexPath` values. This will give you your `firstVisible` and `lastVisible` index paths.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView *)scrollView;
    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(targetContentOffset->x + 1, targetContentOffset->y + 1);
    CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(topLeft.x + scrollView.bounds.size.width - 2, topLeft.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height - 2);

    NSIndexPath *firstVisible = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:topLeft];
    firstVisible = (firstVisible)? firstVisible : [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *lastVisible = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:bottomRight];
    lastVisible = (lastVisible)? lastVisible : [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.model.count-1 inSection:0];

    NSMutableArray *willBeVisibleIndexPaths = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSInteger i=firstVisible.row; i<lastVisible.row; i++) {
        [willBeVisibleIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    }
}
```

This is only a partial solution. Most likely there are cases where `lastVisible` will be `nil`. You need to check for that and set `lastVisible` to whatever the last `indexPath` of the collection should be. It's also possible that `firstVisible` or `lastVisible` could be `nil` due to those points being on header or footer views.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Will work up a more general version per the caveats (and will fix a couple compile errors in the post) then will suggest an edit here.  Can you explain the +1 increment on the topLeft point and -1 decrement on bottomRight?

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to fix any typos. I just typed that in without any testing. The +1/-1 are just to "inset" the points a little bit to help ensure the points are actually inside items at those points.

Comment: Please let me know if you disagree with any of that.

Comment: After some testing, the main problem with the code (fixed in the edit) was reliance on `contentSize` rather than `bounds.size` to form the bottomRight point.  The other issue that I'm still unsure about is how to set the little nudge given to topLeft and bottomRight points.  In my case, I need to add and subtract more than 1 to hit inside a cell.  I think it has to do with the diff between cell height and the collection view height, but I don't know how to compute this reliably.